# Multiple (redundant?) reads of the same file when reading in files into a spark dataframe then using randomSplit()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm reading in a set of files into a pyspark dataframe then using `randomSplit()` to split it into 3 subsets. I noticed from the logging that it seems to read each file of the dataset 4 times. My question is, are the multiple reads necessary (or redundant), and if not, is there a way to cache it to minimize the number of times each file needs to be read?

Example:

My data files are set up this way:

```
/somedir/data/ID=123/123_0.jsonl
/somedir/data/ID=123/123_1.jsonl
/somedir/data/ID=123/123_2.jsonl

/somedir/data/ID=456/456_0.jsonl
/somedir/data/ID=456/456_1.jsonl
/somedir/data/ID=456/456_2.jsonl
```

My script:

```
df = spark.read.json('/somedir/data')
df = df.repartition('ID')
splits = df.randomSplit(weights=[0.6, 0.2, 0.2])

for df_split, label in zip(splits, ['train', 'test', 'validation']):
    df_split.write.partitionBy('ID').json(os.path.join('/somedir/split', label))
```

What I'm noticing in the logs:

```
2020-06-01 00:48:33 INFO  FileScanRDD:54 - Reading File path: file:/somedir/data/ID=123/123_0.jsonl, range: 0-1000000, partition values: [empty row]
2020-06-01 00:48:33 INFO  FileScanRDD:54 - Reading File path: file:/somedir/data/ID=123/123_1.jsonl, range: 0-1000000, partition values: [empty row]
2020-06-01 00:48:33 INFO  FileScanRDD:54 - Reading File path: file:/somedir/data/ID=123/123_2.jsonl, range: 0-1000000, partition values: [empty row]
...some other lines...
2020-06-01 00:48:34 INFO  FileScanRDD:54 - Reading File path: file:///somedir/data/ID=123/123_0.jsonl, range: 0-1000000, partition values: [123]
2020-06-01 00:48:34 INFO  FileScanRDD:54 - Reading File path: file:///somedir/data/ID=123/123_1.jsonl, range: 0-1000000, partition values: [123]
2020-06-01 00:48:34 INFO  FileScanRDD:54 - Reading File path: file:///somedir/data/ID=123/123_2.jsonl, range: 0-1000000, partition values: [123]
...some other lines...
2020-06-01 00:48:35 INFO  FileScanRDD:54 - Reading File path: file:///somedir/data/ID=123/123_0.jsonl, range: 0-1000000, partition values: [123]
2020-06-01 00:48:35 INFO  FileScanRDD:54 - Reading File path: file:///somedir/data/ID=123/123_1.jsonl, range: 0-1000000, partition values: [123]
2020-06-01 00:48:35 INFO  FileScanRDD:54 - Reading File path: file:///somedir/data/ID=123/123_2.jsonl, range: 0-1000000, partition values: [123]
...some other lines...
2020-06-01 00:48:36 INFO  FileScanRDD:54 - Reading File path: file:///somedir/data/ID=123/123_0.jsonl, range: 0-1000000, partition values: [123]
2020-06-01 00:48:36 INFO  FileScanRDD:54 - Reading File path: file:///somedir/data/ID=123/123_1.jsonl, range: 0-1000000, partition values: [123]
2020-06-01 00:48:36 INFO  FileScanRDD:54 - Reading File path: file:///somedir/data/ID=123/123_2.jsonl, range: 0-1000000, partition values: [123]

...repeat for ID=456...
```

I tried adding this line: `splits = [df_split.persist() for df_split in splits]` after the randomSplit() line but before the write loop but it didn't seem to help.

Any thoughts appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

It seems I put the persist() in the wrong part. If I persist right after the spark.read line, the number of reads of the same file is reduced to 2 (no matter how many randomSplit subsets).

```
df = spark.read.json('/somedir/data')
df = df.persist()
```